# How do I get the parameters passed in to the constructor of an attribute?

Tags: c#, reflection, pdb-files

I'm working on a documentation generator. MSDN documentation shows the parameters passed to Attributes when they are applied. Such as `[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]`. How would I get those parameter values and/or the constructor called in my c# code via reflection, pdb file or otherwise?

To clarify> If someone has documented a method that has an attribute on it like so:

```
/// <summary> foo does bar </summary>
[SomeCustomAttribute("a supplied value")]
void Foo() {
  DoBar();
}
```

I want to be able to show the signature of the method in my documentation like so:

```
Signature:

[SomeCustomAttribute("a supplied value")]
void Foo();
```

Comment: Are you asking about coding up your own attribute that takes parameters, or are you looking to find out through reflection the way someone else's attribute has been constructed?

Comment: through reflection the way someone else's attribute has been constructed

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the clarification. I apologize for misunderstanding your question. My method obviously wouldn't give that. You'd probably have to inspect the IL, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a member for which you want to get the custom attributes and the constructor arguments, you can use the following reflection code:

```
MemberInfo member;      // <-- Get a member

var customAttributes = member.GetCustomAttributesData();
foreach (var data in customAttributes)
{
    // The type of the attribute,
    // e.g. "SomeCustomAttribute"
    Console.WriteLine(data.AttributeType);

    foreach (var arg in data.ConstructorArguments)
    {
        // The type and value of the constructor arguments,
        // e.g. "System.String a supplied value"
        Console.WriteLine(arg.ArgumentType + " " + arg.Value);
    }
}
```

To get a member, start with getting the type. There are two ways to get a type.

1. If you have an instance `obj`, call `Type type = obj.GetType();`.
2. If you have a type name `MyType`, do `Type type = typeof(MyType);`.

Then you can find, for example, a particular method. Look at the [reflection documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more info.

```
MemberInfo member = typeof(MyType).GetMethod("Foo");
```

Comment: What about class level attributes? The member part is easy. I haven't figured out how to reflect on class level attribute parameters.

Answer (score 3):

For the `ComVisibileAttribute`, the parameter passed to the constructor becomes the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.value.aspx) property.

```
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public class MyClass { ... }

...

Type classType = typeof(MyClass);
object[] attrs = classType.GetCustomAttributes(true);
foreach (object attr in attrs)
{
    ComVisibleAttribute comVisible = attr as ComVisibleAttribute;
    if (comVisible != null)
    {
        return comVisible.Value // returns true
    }
}
```

Other attributes will follow a similar design pattern.

---

**EDIT**

I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17690/Mono-Cecil-The-Most-Powerful-Tool-You-ve-Ever-Hear) about [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) that describes how to do something very similar. This looks it ought to do what you need.

```
foreach (CustomAttribute eca in classType.CustomAttributes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}({1})]", eca, eca.ConstructorParameters.Join(", "));
}
```